# In-place modification, insertion or removal in the same function for hash maps in Rust

Tags: rust, hashmap

Say I have a hash map `m: HashMap<K, V>`, a key `k: K` and a value `v: V`, and would like to do the following:

- If `m` does not contain a value at index `k`, insert `v` at index `k`.
- If `m` contains a value `w` at index `k`, apply a function `fn combine(x: V, y: V) -> Option<V>` to `v` and `w`, and:

  - If the result is `None`, remove the entry at index `k` from `m`.
  - If the result is `Some(u)`, replace the value at index `k` by `u`.

Is there a way to do this "in-place", without calling functions that access, modify or remove the value at `k` multiple times?

I would also like to avoid copying data, so ideally one shouldn't need to clone `v` to feed the clones into `insert` and `combine` separately.

I could rewrite `combine` to use (mutable) references (or inline it), but the wish of not copying data still remains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Digging deeper into the [`Entry` documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html), I noticed that the variants of the `Entry` enum offer functions to modify, remove or insert entries in-place.

After taking `std::collections::hash_map::Entry` into scope, one could do the following:

```
match m.entry(k) {
    Entry::Occupied(mut oe) => {
        let w = oe.get_mut();
        match combine(v, w) {
            Some(u) => { *w = u; },
            None    => { oe.remove_entry(); },
        }
    },
    Entry::Vacant(ve) => { ve.insert(v); },
}
```

([Here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b654c1311467157522af00a6af1d4310) is a PoC in the Rust playground.)

This, however, requires `combine` to take a (mutable) reference as its second argument (which is fine in my case).

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it in one access, one write and one key-deletion in total in the worst case. The last key-deletion should not be necessary, but I'm not certain it can be done. I gave it my best so far. I hope this helps!

Okay, so I think we want to use the [Entry API](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry).

The full method list for `Entry` is [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html#methods).

I think we'd do it in the following order:

- If `m` contains a value `w` at index `k`: (two more steps)
- Or insert `v` at index `k`.

This can be done by using `.and_modify` and then `.or_insert`. Something like this:

```rust
let map = // ... Initialize the map

// Do stuff to it
// ...

// Our important bit:

let mut delete_entry = false;

map.entry(k)
   .and_modify(|w| { // If the entry exists, we modify it

     let u = combine(v, w);

     match u {

       Some(y) => *w = y;

       None => delete_entry = true;
       }
     }
   )
   .or_insert(v); // If it doesn't, we insert v

if delete_entry {
  map.remove(k);
}
```

I don't think there's a way to do all three things without that last `map.remove` access, so this is my best attempt for now.

Comment: Thanks, this is close, but the problem is that one cannot call `or_insert(v)` after calling `combine(v, w)` in the closure that comes before because both require `v` to be moved.

(Also I see that I'll probably need to change `combine` to use a (mutable) reference to `w`, but I'm fine with that. However, I still would  like to avoid copying/cloning `v`.)

Comment: Ohh, I see. If you need `v` to be moved then yes, you're out of luck.